# Python - instance of a class from another file accessing a var from the main script

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

am making a text-based RPG game where i split the game into a lot of files containing scripts for creatures classes and  weapons, example: `classes/mobs/goblin.py`, and i have a global list for entities so when a mob attack something it finds that thing's location from that global list, but the instance class from `classes/mobs/default.py` can't access the list on the `main.py` file.

example codes:

main.py:

```
entity_list = ['test']
x = classes.mobs.default.goblin()
x.attack()
```

goblin.py:

```
class goblin():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def attack(self):
        print(entity_list)
```

is there a workaround? thanks in advance.

Comment: you could create a parameter to pass to the method `attack` and use `x.attack(entity_list)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a design flaw, and while you can push imports down into functions, it's better to solve the underlying problem.

I think the best option here is to create a `Context` class to hold the global state, `context.py`:

```
_CONTEXT = None
def context():
    global _CONTEXT
    if _CONTEXT is None:
        _CONTEXT = Context()
    return _CONTEXT

class Context(object):
    def __init__(self):
          self.entity_list = ['test']
```

you can then use it freely in `goblin.py`:

```
from path.to.context import context

class Goblin(object):
    def attack(self):
        print(context().entity_list)
```

and `main.py`:

```
x = classes.mobs.default.Goblin()
x.attack()
```

if you at some point want to implement save/replay/network play, you can extend the `context`:

```
class Context(object):
    def __init__(self):
          self.__events = []
          self.entity_list = ['test']

    def _addevent(self, name, *options):
        self.__events.append(name, options)
        # and/or send the event to other processes/users/etc.

    def create(self, cls, *args, **kwargs):
        self._addevent('create', cls, args, kwargs)
        return cls(*args, **kwargs)

    def call(self, obj, method, *args, **kwargs):
        self._addevent('call', obj, method, args, kwargs)
        return getattr(obj, method)(*args, **kwargs)
```

your `main.py` would then look like:

```
from path.to.context import context
x = context().create(classes.mobs.default.goblin)
context().call(x, 'attack')
```

the awkwardness in syntax can be hidden with meta classes and decorators if need be.

Answer (score 0):

```
def attack(self):
    from .main import entity_list
    print(entity_list)
```

Importing inside methods or functions can be used to cause delayed imports.

This way, the fact that main.py may have to import goblin.py won't throw you in a circular import situation, since the importing of main.py in the goblin file is delayed until its needed.

And it cause no performance impact as well: the main and goblin modules are already in memory and loaded, the import statement just makes an assignment to an object that is already there.

Comment: the `.main` part didn't work out for me so i changed it to `from main import entity_list` and it worked, but this causes the `main` script to run twice.

Comment: it won t cause the main script to run twice: it is imported just once by Python and variables defined in it are available to be imported from other scripts. Python is smarter than just running a file it has already run in the current process.